# Change length of operation depending on a value

Tags: python

### Context

I am trying to create a program that gets the product of all n pairs in a number reading from left to right

For example, in the number 2345678:

- The product of all 2 pairs would be 2*3 = 6, 3*4=12, 4*5=20, 5*6=30 etc...
- The product of all 3 pairs would be 2*3*4=24,3*4*5=60, 4*5*6=120 etc...

I have completed most of the solution to the problem, but I cannot create an operation that can adapt for any value of n

### Code

```
num = 2345678
num = str(num)


n = 2
start_pos = 0

for i in range(start_pos,len(num)):
    try:
        x += 1
        t = int(num[i]) * int(num[i+1]) # hardcoded for n = 2
        print(t)
        start_pos += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

### Operation for different n values

`n = 2`: `t = int(num[i]) * int(num[i+1])`

`n = 3`: `t = int(num[i]) * int(num[i+1]) * int(num[i+2])`

`n = 4`: `t = int(num[i]) * int(num[i+1]) * int(num[i+2]) * int(num[i+3])`

`n = 5`: `t = int(num[i]) * int(num[i+1]) * int(num[i+2]) * int(num[i+3]) * int(num[i+4])`

How could I create an operation that can adapt for any value of n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an iterative solution without using any pythonic operator, you can simply add an inner `for` to iterate from `i` to `i+n`, and then accumulate the product of numbers in a variable `t`. Like this:

```
num = 2345678
num = str(num)


n = 3
start_pos = 0
x = 0
for i in range(start_pos,len(num)):
    try:

        t = 1
        for j in range(i, i+n):
            t = t * int(num[j])

        print(t)

    except IndexError:
        break
```

Output:

```
24
60
120
210
336
```

Comment: Starting at `i+1` and setting `t = int(num[i])` is equivalent to what I think is the much nicer: starting from `i` and setting `t = 1`

Comment: You're right.  It is much more elegant. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a typical problem for recursion:

```
def recurse(int_list, times):
    if times == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return int(int_list[0]) * recurse(int_list[1:], times - 1)

num = 2345678
num_string = str(num)
n = 5
recurse(num_string, n)
```

Comment: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Comment: Don't forget to str() your number, as you do in the second line of your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it similarly to what you tried, using loops:

```
def products(num, n):
    num = str(num)
    digits = [int(digit) for digit in num]
    out = []
    for i in range(0, len(num)-n+1):
        product = 1
        for digit in digits[i:i+n]:
            product *= digit
        out.append(product)
    return out

print(products(num, 3))
# [24, 60, 120, 210, 336]
```

Or, using more advanced features:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def products2(num, n):
    num = str(num)
    digits = list(map(int, num))
    out = [reduce(operator.mul, digits[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(num)-n+1)]
    return out

print(products2(num, 3))
# [24, 60, 120, 210, 336]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `functools.reduce` is designed to operate on successive pairs from a list:

```
from functools import reduce
number = 2345678
numbers = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
product = reduce((lambda x,y : x*y), numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using recursion:

```
num = 23456789
num = str(num)

n = 2
start_pos = 0


def nvalues(num, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return int(num[i]) * nvalues(num[1:], n-1)



for i in range(start_pos,len(num)):
    try:
        val = nvalues(num, n)
        print val

    except IndexError:
        break
```

Comment: `n=2` returns `6,12,20,30,42,56,72,36,8,6`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce


def func(number, n):
    nums = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    z = zip(*[nums[i:] for i in range(n)])
    r = starmap(lambda *x: reduce(mul, x), z)
    return list(r)

print(func(2345678, 2))
# [6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56]

print(func(2345678, 3))
# [24, 60, 120, 210, 336]
```